# User name won't display

Tags: php, mysql

I try to display the user log in to the memberadd.php where i want to add other members, however, it doesn't display, instead it is blank. I post both the member add code and the log in code, it has something to do how the memberadd php didn't received the variable from the other files?

this is the memberadd code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/chtml-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web Programming :: Assignment 2" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Web, programming" />
    <title>Member Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>My Member System</h1>

</body>
</html>

<?php
session_start();
require_once('sqlconnect.inc.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['membername']))
    {
    echo "<p>Welcome back". "<br />".$_SESSION['membername']."</p>";

$conn = @mysqli_connect($host, 
        $user, 
        $pswd, 
        $dbnm);

    if (!$conn) {
        echo "<p>Database connection failure</p>"; 
    } else {

    @mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbnm)
        or die ("Database not available");
    }

    $query = "SELECT member_name FROM team";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if(!$result) {
        echo "<p>Error with: ", $query, "</p>";
        } else {
        echo "<table width='10%' border='1'>";
        echo "<tr><th>Member</th></tr>";

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>",$row["member_name"],"</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    }
    //
?>
```

below is the login page

```
<?php
        session_start();
        require_once('sqlconnect.inc.php');

        if (isset($_POST["login"]))
        {
        $conn = @mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pswd);
                    if (!$conn) {
                    echo "<p>Database connection failure</p>"; 
                    } else {

        $selectDatabase = @mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbnm)
                    or die("<p>The database is not available.</p>");
                    }

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $passw = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT member_email FROM team WHERE member_email = '$email' AND password = '$passw'";

        $queryResult = @mysqli_query($conn,$query)
                        or die ("<p>Unable to execute query.</p>". "<p>Error code" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn))."</p>";


        if(mysqli_num_rows($queryResult) == 0) //user is not found
        {
            header('Location: login.php');
        }else{

        if(mysqli_num_rows($queryResult) == 1)  
        {
            echo ("<p>User is found, Successful login!</p>");   
            echo('<p><a href="memberadd.php">member add</a> </p>');
            echo('<p><a href="memberremove.php">List/Remove member</a> </p>');
            echo('<p><a href="logout.php">Log out</a> </p>');
            exit();

            $query2 = "SELECT member_name FROM team WHERE member_email = '$email' AND password= '$passw'";

            $queryResult2 = @mysqli_query($conn, $query2)
                        or die ("<p>Unable to execute query.</p>". "<p>Error code" . mysqli_errno($conn) .":" . mysqli_error($conn))."</p>";


            $array = mysqli_fetch_row($queryResult2);       
            $_SESSION['membername'] = $array[0];
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<p>Email and password do not match</p>";
            echo'<p><a href="index.php">Home page</a> </p>';
        }
        }
        }


?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/chtml-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="Web Programming :: Assignment 2" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="Web, programming" />
    <title>Member Login</title>
</head>

<body>

<form id='login' action='login.php' method='POST'>
        <fieldset >
            <legend><h1>My Team System Log in Page</h1></legend>
            <?php $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) : ''; ?>
            <label for='email' >Email:</label>
                <input type='text' name='email' id='email' maxlength="50"  value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
            </div>
                    <br />
            <div class="elements">
            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
                <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />
            </div>
                    <br />
            <div class="submit">
                <input type='submit' name='login' value='Login' />
                <input type='reset' name='Submit' value='Clear' />
                    <br />
            <div class="elements">
            <a href="index.php">Home</a> 
        </fieldset>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove all those `@` signs!  Don't suppress MySQL errors.

Comment: This is just a made up example right? You aren't actually doing `$query = "SELECT member_email FROM team WHERE member_email = '$email' AND password = '$passw'";`, right?

Comment: sorry, I solved it now :s, I had the session name wrong in my registration file, so now all the session is consistent, my apology! Thank you so much for the contribution though!

Answer (score 0):

You set the session as `membername` but you then try to call `name`. As in, you should correct the bit where you display the user's name into `$_SESSION['membername']`.

Comment: Sorry, i post this code when i tried to figure and play around, I've tried that already and it didn't work unfortunately, thanks though

Comment: sorry, I solved it now :s, I had the session name wrong in my registration file, so now all the session is consistent, my apology! Thank you so much for the contribution though!

Answer (score 0):

Blank screen is usually a parse error...

```
echo "<p>Error with: ", $query, "</p>";
```

Should be

```
echo "<p>Error with: ".$query."</p>"; 


echo "<td>",$row["member_name"],"</td>";
```

Should be

```
echo "<td>".$row["member_name"]."</td>";
```

Comment: It's 100% valid to use commas with `echo`.  Docs:http://php.net/echo Example: https://eval.in/59290

Comment: [The more you know](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3rhQc666Sg), and [knowing is half the battle](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pele5vptVgc) :-)

Comment: haha, :), best place to learn new stuff here in stackoverflow!

Comment: sorry, I solved it now :s, I had the session name wrong in my registration file, so now all the session is consistent, my apology! Thank you so much for the contribution though!

Answer (score 0):

3 errors I see -
1. your `session_start()` is not at the top/start of your code.
2. you echo before setting your session value
3. you use `exit();` after your echo and before setting your session value.

---

also, you are wide open to sql injection, and you should hash your passwords.

Comment: Sorry, i post this code after i play around when error occurred, I did place the session_start() before at the very top of the code. For the exit(); I do two exit(); both before session and after echo?

Comment: Your posted code sample does not have `session_start()` at the top. You have it after your html `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" .....`. If you use `exit();` it will end your script and so if this occurs before you set your session values, they will never be executed, as you exited out of the code before.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can tell you about what I see:
You set the session of the member name like this

```
$_SESSION['membername'] = $array[0];
```

But in memberadd.php  you retrieve it like this:

```
echo "<p>Welcome back". "<br />".$_SESSION['name']."</p>";
```

So you should change to the same name you set it to :

```
echo "<p>Welcome back". "<br />".$_SESSION['membername']."</p>";
```

Comment: sorry, I solved it now :s, I had the session name wrong in my registration file, so now all the session is consistent, my apology! Thank you so much for the contribution though!

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry guys, I've made a mistake on the early file I did, which is the signup file where people registered, and I set the session name there ['name'] instead of ['membername']. Is all fine now.